# Working of setSelectionFrom: to: anchor: highlight:?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to know the working of the following NSMatrix method.
I'm not actually getting as mentioned in below link:

[NSMatrix - Selecting multiple cells programmatically](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/14308-nsmatrix-selecting-multiple-cells-programmatically.html)

```
[aButtonMatrix setSelectionFrom:2 to:3 anchor:2 highlight:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSelectionFrom:to:anchor:highlight:` programmatically selects a range of cells.

In general you should start by checking the Apple documentation, not some 3rd party content that might be (and often is) outdated by the time you read it.

From the docs:

*startPos, endPos, and anchorPos are cell positions, counting from 0 at the upper left cell of the receiver, in row order. For example, the third cell in the top row would be number 2.*

*To simulate dragging without a modifier key, deselecting anything that was selected before, call deselectAllCells before calling this method.*